# How do I make a Kali Linux live USB with persistence

Tags: partitioning, kali-linux, chromebook, liveusb, persistence

I bought a pretty large USB drive to turn into a live USB to use to boot Kali Linux on. I am doing this on my Chromebook, so I used the tool "Chromebook Recovery Utility" to flash the file (kali-linux-2020.1-live-amd64.bin, I changed the file extension from .iso to .bin because of compatibility issues with Chromebook Recovery Utility) and It booted perfectly fine!

I then tried to make it persistent. That's when I realized that it would be harder than I first thought. Here are some of the problems that I encountered:

1. I tried to do it on a mac, but I had issues getting a partition that I could change the size of.
2. I tried some of Kali's instructions, but that ended in me corrupting the USB, so I reformatted it and it was like normal.
3. I tried using GParted, and that started out promising but ended in me having an error message that was not mentioned in the article.
4. Almost everything that I looked at relied on you using a Windows computer and getting MiniTool Partition Wizard, which I couldn't get.

So here I am, asking for help. If you do decide to help, I am on a Chromebook with USB-Boot enabled, I have Crouton running with `xfce4` because the `Linux(Beta)` feature wasn't in my Chromebooks settings.

How would I be able to make my Live USB persistent? Any help is appreciated. Also, please don't shun me for making a bad question, I really tried hard to make this a good question. If this is the wrong place to post it to, please tell me which one would be better, but don't be mean about it.

Comment: People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](https://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Comment: @DavidPostill ok, I'm sorry. I'll try to fix that.

Comment: @DavidPostill is this better? Sorry if it's bad.